# Responsive footer using media queries

Tags: html, css, media-queries, responsive

I'm trying to stack my footer elements on top of each other in tablet and mobile view. There are 3 sections of my footer (contact, logo, and copyright info). The media queries I've added aren't doing anything. Currently the 3 sections are going on top of each other, but look like a staircase, not blocks directly on top of one another.

This is what the live preview looks like:

[image]
Could someone tell me what I'm missing? I've just started coding & manipulating templates I've found online. The CSS and HTML codes are below.

[UPDATED live preview:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ZmCo.png)

```css
.site-footer {
  padding: 5em 0;
  background: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 13px;
}

.site-footer p:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.site-footer a {
  color: #f4b214;
}

.site-footer a:hover {
  color: #f4b214;
}

.site-footer h3 {
  font-size: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.site-footer .footer-link li {
  line-height: 1.5;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.site-footer hr {
  width: 100%;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 320px) {
  .site-footer .container .row .col-sm-12 {
    display: block;
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .site-footer .container .row .col-md-12 {
    display: block;
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<footer class="site-footer" role="contentinfo">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
        <ul class="list-unstyled footer-link">
          <li class="d-flex"><span class="mr-3">Office:</span><span class="text-black">439 South Florida Avenue 
                  <br>Suite 202
                  <br>Lakeland, Florida 33801</span></li>
          <li class="d-flex"><span class="mr-3">Phone:</span><span class="text-black">863 683 9297</span></li>
          <li class="d-flex"><span class="mr-3">Hours:</span><span class="text-black">Monday - Friday 
                  <br>8:30 AM to 5:30 PM
                  <br>Meetings by Appointment Only</span></li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
        <a href="index.html"><img src="img/MR_full_logo.png" style="max-width: 200px" class="center" /></a>
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
        <!-- Link back to Colorlib can't be removed. Template is licensed under CC BY 3.0. -->
        <p align="right" class="copyright">Copyright &copy;
          <script>
            document.write(new Date().getFullYear());
          </script> All rights reserved <br> This template is made with <i class="fa fa-heart-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> by <a href="https://colorlib.com" target="_blank">Colorlib</a></p>
        <!-- Link back to Colorlib can't be removed. Template is licensed under CC BY 3.0. -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: Presumably the class `center` on the image is positioning the image in the center. And you have `align="right"` on the copyright paragraph so it will be aligned to the right. You need to override this positioning within your media queries to position the elements where you want them. Try `text-align: left`

Answer (score 0):

Hey try the following code and check the output it will fullfill your requirement. Use @media only screen and (max-width: 768px) to get required output in mobile and tab view. width up to 768 refers to tablet view.

```css
.site-footer {
  padding: 5em 0;
  background: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 13px;
}

.site-footer p:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.site-footer a {
  color: #f4b214;
}

.site-footer a:hover {
  color: #f4b214;
}

.site-footer h3 {
  font-size: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.site-footer .footer-link li {
  line-height: 1.5;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.site-footer hr {
  width: 100%;
}


@media only screen and (min-width: 320px) {
    .site-footer  .container .row .col-sm-12 { 
        display: block; 
        float: none;
        width: 100%;
    }
  }


@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .site-footer .container .row .col-md-12 { 
        display: block; 
        float: none;
        width: 100%;
    }
  }
  @media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .site-footer{
      text-align: center;
    }

  .site-footer .footer-link li {
    list-style: none;
  }
  .site-footer p:last-child {
      text-align: center;
  }
}
```

```html
<footer class="site-footer" role="contentinfo">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
        <ul class="list-unstyled footer-link">
          <li class="d-flex"><span class="mr-3">Office:</span><span class="text-black">439 South Florida Avenue 
              <br>Suite 202
              <br>Lakeland, Florida 33801</span></li>
          <li class="d-flex"><span class="mr-3">Phone:</span><span class="text-black">863 683 9297</span></li>
          <li class="d-flex"><span class="mr-3">Hours:</span><span class="text-black">Monday - Friday 
              <br>8:30 AM to 5:30 PM
              <br>Meetings by Appointment Only</span></li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
          <a href="index.html"><img src="img/MR_full_logo.png" style="max-width: 200px" class="center" /></a> 
        </div>

      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
        <!-- Link back to Colorlib can't be removed. Template is licensed under CC BY 3.0. -->
        <p align="right" class="copyright">Copyright &copy;<script>document.write(new Date().getFullYear());</script> All rights reserved <br> This template is made with <i class="fa fa-heart-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> by <a href="https://colorlib.com" target="_blank">Colorlib</a></p>
        <!-- Link back to Colorlib can't be removed. Template is licensed under CC BY 3.0. -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: I updated the code to what you gave me, and it worked for the logo and copyright elements, but for some reason the contact info is still aligning left. I would like it to all be centered & have more padding around each element. Can I add a screenshot here to show the progress?

Comment: I added a picture of what the footer looks like currently on the main post. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Can you provide me your site url?

Answer (score 0):

it is because your p tag in the last div has a property align="right", float it left on small screen or use text-align left and for your image you can give text align left